# Why do i get this error: "Command/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1"?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, fbconnect

I want to login with facebook account in my application. For that i read developers.facebook.com documentation. I have installed everything. When i put FBConnect in my application, then i get this error:

```
 Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

 Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RunnoNavTest.app/RunnoNavTest normal i386
 cd "/Users/arashsaeidihaghi/Documents/Mahmood/iPhone Apps/RunnoNavTest"
 setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
 setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk "-L/Users/arashsaeidihaghi/Documents/Mahmood/iPhone Apps/RunnoNavTest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/arashsaeidihaghi/Documents/Mahmood/iPhone Apps/RunnoNavTest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Users/arashsaeidihaghi/Documents/Mahmood/iPhone Apps/RunnoNavTest/build/RunnoNavTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RunnoNavTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/RunnoNavTest.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MediaPlayer -framework MapKit -lz.1.2.3 -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -o "/Users/arashsaeidihaghi/Documents/Mahmood/iPhone Apps/RunnoNavTest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RunnoNavTest.app/RunnoNavTest"

 ld: duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain in /Users/arashsaeidihaghi/Documents/Mahmood/iPhone Apps/RunnoNavTest/build/RunnoNavTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RunnoNavTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonBase-8058DE1040F45B54.o and /Users/arashsaeidihaghi/Documents/Mahmood/iPhone Apps/RunnoNavTest/build/RunnoNavTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RunnoNavTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonBase-4E4B4560D6FF6850.o
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

 ld: duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain in /Users/arashsaeidihaghi/Documents/Mahmood/iPhone Apps/RunnoNavTest/build/RunnoNavTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RunnoNavTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonBase-8058DE1040F45B54.o and /Users/arashsaeidihaghi/Documents/Mahmood/iPhone Apps/RunnoNavTest/build/RunnoNavTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RunnoNavTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonBase-4E4B4560D6FF6850.o
```

When i remove that FBConnect, then it again works fine. That FBConnect has a JSON folder and my application also has a JSON folder. But files in both folder have different names. How can i remove this error and make it work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the file in the JSON folder is a duplicate.